# ingress controller multiple hosts

Tags: kubernetes

Can I add multiple hosts to the Ingress controller so that they refer to the same target group in the aws load balancer? Example:

````
  rules:
  - host: ["foobar.com", "api.foobar.com",  "status.foobar.com"]
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: foobar
          servicePort: 80 ```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; no

---

Long answer:

In [k8s source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/api/blob/master/networking/v1beta1/types.go#L159) you can see that `host` field's data type is string, so you cannot use array of strings in that place.

But you should be able to do the following:

```
rules:
- host: "foobar.com"
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: foobar
        servicePort: 80
- host: "api.foobar.com"
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: foobar
        servicePort: 80
- host: "status.foobar.com"
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: foobar
        servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hostname wildcards if you are using Kubernetes > 1.18 version.

For more information check these links:

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/basic-configuration/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

```
rules:
- host: "foobar.com"
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: foobar
        servicePort: 80
- host: "*.foobar.com"
  http:
    paths:
    - backend:
        serviceName: foobar
        servicePort: 80
```